WCF service not able to deserialize xml
I'm using a WCF service and this is my service method:
[ServiceContract]
public interface II3ReceiverService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string result(Envelope envelope);
}

This is the initial request part for reference:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:drug="http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <OriginatorSystem>I3Logix</OriginatorSystem>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <drug:result soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

I get this error:

OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'result' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'drug:result' and namespace 'http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr'

How do I fix this?
Update
Im able to got hit the service method but payload is null.
Here is my updated code
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr")]
  public interface II3ReceiverService
  {
      [OperationContract(Action = "http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr/result")]
      string result(Envelope report);
  }

  // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
  /// <remarks/>
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
  public partial class Envelope
  {

      private EnvelopeHeader headerField;

      private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

      /// <remarks/>
      public EnvelopeHeader Header
      {
          get
          {
              return this.headerField;
          }
          set
          {
              this.headerField = value;
          }
      }

      /// <remarks/>
      public EnvelopeBody Body
      {
          get
          {
              return this.bodyField;
          }
          set
          {
              this.bodyField = value;
          }
      }
  }

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
  public partial class EnvelopeHeader
  {

      private string originatorSystemField;

      /// <remarks/>
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
      public string OriginatorSystem
      {
          get
          {
              return this.originatorSystemField;
          }
          set
          {
              this.originatorSystemField = value;
          }
      }
  }

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
  public partial class EnvelopeBody
  {

      private result resultField;

      /// <remarks/>
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr")]
      public result result
      {
          get
          {
              return this.resultField;
          }
          set
          {
              this.resultField = value;
          }
      }
  }

Web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Application Settings -->
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <!-- System.Web Settings -->
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    </system.web>

    <!-- System.ServiceModel Settings -->
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_I3ReceiverService">
                    <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <services>
            <service name="I3Receiver.I3ReceiverService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="I3Receiver.II3ReceiverService" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:64863/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
        </protocolMapping>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                            logMalformedMessages="true"
                            logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                            logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
        </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <!-- System.WebServer Settings -->
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

    <!-- System.Diagnostics Settings -->
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\WcfTrace.svclog"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="messages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\WcfMessages.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>


How can we resolve it now? much appreciated

Have you tried removing xmlns:drug="http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr" and replacing <drug:result with <result?

This request payload given by client so I cant change it

Looks like your service was generated from a WSDL document that is not compatible with this response.

Try replacing [ServiceContract] with [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr")]

I performed a schema check of the xml.  There is a failure with node : I3Logix Where did you get this node?  It is missing a namespace.  Right now it defaults to the drug namespace which does not have then node OriginatorSystem.

This error is caused by a mismatch between the message structure expected by the WCF service and the message structure actually received. Specifically, WCF expects to find an XML element named result with a namespace of http://tempuri.org/ in the message body, but actually receives an element named result with a namespace of http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr. As a result, WCF was unable to properly parse the incoming SOAP message, resulting in an OperationFormatter exception being thrown.
So I would like to make two suggestions:
Use the automatic property OriginatorSystem directly, and the compiler will automatically generate the fields that support storage.
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://drug.gateway.mvp.na_svr")]
public class Result
{
    
}

2.Configure a server's log file to see what exactly the soap you are sending out further confirms the problem.
Tracing and Message Logging

Thank you for the response. I updated the question. Now Im receiving the request but request is null

Hello, have you tried my method below to generate a log file to query what the SOAP messages received and sent look like? In fact, the cause of the problem may be that the SOAP information does not match, but the structure is similar. So we need to look at the contents of this log file first. Secondly, you can also check the configuration of the client (similar to whether the contract and bindings are the same as the server).

Hello QI. I am not able to generate log file. Im trying to do so. However, Im using SoapUI

In fact, SOAPUI can set the format and content of the request to be sent by yourself. The problem you're currently having is that you are customizing the content you send on Soapui to the WCF service, but getting the payload is empty? I'm currently speculating that the reason is that the type format is correct, but the content is not transferred. This and WCF acceptance are also related to the impact.
